# Error while applying a default constraint

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ddl

I'm getting error saying:

> incorrect syntax near for.

```
CREATE TABLE Test       (ID       INT          not null IDENTITY Primary key,
                         CreatedBy      VARCHAR(20)  not null,
                         CreatedDate    DATETIME     not null,
                         UpdatedBy      VARCHAR(20)  not null,
                         LastUpdated    DATETIME     not null,

CONSTRAINT Test_CreatedBy   DEFAULT USER_NAME() FOR CreatedBy,
CONSTRAINT Test_CreatedDate DEFAULT GETDATE()   FOR CreatedDate,
CONSTRAINT Test_UpdatedBy   DEFAULT USER_NAME() FOR UpdatedBy,
CONSTRAINT Test_LastUpdated DEFAULT GETDATE()   FOR LastUpdated)
go
```

Comment: where is the error near ?

Comment: which version sql you are using ?

Comment: @Ven The error is near FOR version is SQL Server management studio 14.0.17224.0

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have already mentioned it the error is incorrect syntax near FOR

Comment: It is always suggested to create constraints inline with column definition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE Test       
(
ID             INT          not null IDENTITY Primary key,
CreatedBy      VARCHAR(20)  not null
    CONSTRAINT Test_CreatedBy   DEFAULT USER_NAME(),
CreatedDate    DATETIME     not null
    CONSTRAINT Test_CreatedDate DEFAULT GETDATE(),
UpdatedBy      VARCHAR(20)  not null
    CONSTRAINT Test_UpdatedBy   DEFAULT USER_NAME(),
LastUpdated    DATETIME     not null
    CONSTRAINT Test_LastUpdated DEFAULT GETDATE()
);
GO
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5a243f67e253c73e0b4dccaa7b16b483)*

Or if you prefer use ALTER TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE Test       
(
ID             INT          not null IDENTITY Primary key,
CreatedBy      VARCHAR(20)  not null,
CreatedDate    DATETIME     not null,
UpdatedBy      VARCHAR(20)  not null,
LastUpdated    DATETIME     not null
);
GO

ALTER TABLE Test
    ADD CONSTRAINT Test_CreatedBy   DEFAULT USER_NAME() FOR CreatedBy;
GO

ALTER TABLE Test
    ADD CONSTRAINT Test_CreatedDate DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR CreatedDate;
GO

ALTER TABLE Test
    ADD CONSTRAINT Test_UpdatedBy   DEFAULT USER_NAME() FOR UpdatedBy;
GO

ALTER TABLE Test
    ADD CONSTRAINT Test_LastUpdated DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR LastUpdated;
GO
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a520da86c29cb80a6bae719688ac250d)*

Answer (score 1):

You could define the *constraint* as column level as follow

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) Primary key,
CreatedBy  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT USER_NAME(),
CreatedDate  DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
UpdatedBy VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT USER_NAME(),
LastUpdated DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE());
GO
```